# Do Java HashSets act on String references, or values?

Tags: java, string, reference, hashset

I have the following.

```
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
String strB1 = "B";
String strB2 = "B";

set1.add( "A" );
set1.add( strB1 );
set2.add( strB2 );

set1.removeAll( set2 );
```

Will set1 end up containing only "A", or will it contain "B" as well?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: (Very few standard data-structures in Java act on object *identity* as most are *equality*. The ones that do will let you know. Also, there is only *one* string object representing "B" here.)

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable question.  There is no reason to suspect that just because the code does one thing when run that it **always** will have that behavior, or that the behavior is portable from platform to platform.

Comment: If you couldn't test it yourself because you don't have installed tools you can always use [this site](http://ideone.com/o1aIS).

Comment: @templatetypedef If the question went on to say "I tried it and got *X* result, but I don't understand why and I'm not sure if I can count on that behavior. I read the docs but don't quite understand if when they say *Y* that applies to this situation." I'd agree with you. As it stands, it just comes off as "I'd rather ask SO than compile and run it."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) uses object *equality* ([`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)), not *identity* ("reference equals").

Additionally, `HashSet` uses `Object.hashCode` for the hashing function.

Unfortunately, to "know" this, takes a little bit of "reading into" of the documentation and knowing how a hash is implemented. From the documentation for `HashSet.contains`:

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : **o.equals(e)**).

The more general [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) documentation says:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that **e1.equals(e2)**, and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

With *very few* exceptions, such as [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), the data-structures in Java work on *equality* and not *identity*.

Thus, to answer the question, HashSet works on the "String values".

(This example can be particularly misleading due to String intern'ing, but that doesn't change the above as identity implies equality even if the converse is not true.)

Comment: Thanks pst.  I wasn't absolutely sure (short of trying) if the removeAll() API adhered to the .equals() comparison method as well, as it doesn't explicitly state that in the documentation as it does for the other APIs.  And thanks to Pshemo's comment above, I now know about http://ideone.com/ for cases where I don't have a compiler handy on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are treated specially. For optimization purposes any string literal is cached and reused. Thus strB1 and strB2 will hold the same reference and as a result set1 should only contain "A" after the code is executed.

At least according to the Java documentation and SCJP training books.

But as posted in the comment, it is quicker to just try it than posting here...

Comment: this example posted would work the same way with strings or non string objects since hashsets operate based on the equals (and hashcode) method. So if the two objects are equal, whether they the same identity or not, the remove method will remove it.

Comment: It doesn't have anything with interned String literals. The behavior would be the same with any kind of objects.